# How to disable streetview using gwt?

Tags: google-maps, gwt

There is a "person" icon which allows user to view "Street View". I don't want this functionality on my map, is there a way to remove it or disable it? And I am not using JavaScript I am doing it using GWT.

Google-Maps v3 am using.

```
private void initMap() {
        mapVp.setSize(String.valueOf(BodyPanel.bodyWidth - 505),
                String.valueOf(BodyPanel.bodyHeight + 5));
        LatLng myLatLng = LatLng.create(24.440099, 46.843498);
        final MapOptions myOptions = MapOptions.create();
        myOptions.setZoom(5);
        myOptions.setCenter(myLatLng);
        setStreetViewControl(myOptions.getJso(), false); //Added now
        myOptions.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
        myOptions.setMapTypeControl(true);
        Timer load = new Timer() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                map = GoogleMap.create(mapVp.getElement(), myOptions);
                hPanel.add(LoginDashboardModule
                        .mapLegends(map, "Live Tracking"));
            }
        };
        load.schedule(1000);        
    }
```

**This is my code**
I am getting error after adding this line       setStreetViewControl(myOptions.getJso(), false);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just used the line below and got the output.

myOptions.setStreetViewControl(false);

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with JSNI.

```
public static MapWidget createMapWidget(double lat, double lng,
        final String width, final String height, int zoomLevel) {
    // Set the options of the map widget.
    MapOptions options = new MapOptions();
    options.setZoom(zoomLevel);
    options.setMapTypeId(new MapTypeId().getRoadmap());
    setStreetViewControl(options.getJso(), false);
    options.setCenter(new LatLng(lat, lng));

    /* The map widget */
    final MapWidget mapWidget = new MapWidget(options);
    mapWidget.setWidth(width);
    mapWidget.setHeight(height);
    return mapWidget;
}

public static native void setStreetViewControl(JavaScriptObject obj,
        boolean control) /*-{
    if (obj)
        obj.streetViewControl = control;
}-*/;
```

Comment: I have edited my question posted my code above, I am getting error for setStreetViewControl(); Is there any thing missing. Error showing getJso() is undefined for the type MapOptions.

Comment: What implementation of the Google Maps API for GWT do you use ? http://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api or http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maps3 or https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/ ?

Comment: The correction I given is for the https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/ version.
The http://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api version has a setStreetViewControl implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview?csw=1#StreetViewMapUsage) by setting *streetViewControl* to *false*. So I assume the GWT wrapper does provide a similar option.